# How to load data into another table

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have a large table called t1 which has many columns (c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8, c9, c10).

I have another table named t2 which only has column c1.

How I can populate this table from t2?

I know there is a command called CTAS. But that will create table as well. But I just want to populate the table t2 and t2 table already exists in the database.

I want to populate t2.c1 with all distinct t1.c1.

Comment: What is your expected outcome? 10 rows in t2 for one row of t1 or you just want to populate t2.c1 with t1.c1?

Answer (score 2):

You may use an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` here:

```sql
INSERT INTO t2 (c1)
SELECT DISTINCT c1
FROM t1;
```

But actually, you might also just want to create a view which returns all distinct `c1` values from the first table instead:

```sql
CREATE VIEW c1_view AS
SELECT DISTINCT c1
FROM t1;
```

This avoids formally creating a second table, and it also avoids the problem of the the `c1` values in this second table becoming stale and out of date as the data in the first table changes.